# dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN3WTF19initializeThreadingEv - webkit MacOSX

Tags: xcode, macos, safari, webkit, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to run safari/webkit from custom build, but at the end I get error like in the topic. From the beginning.

My Os : `MacOS Catalina ver 10.15.5`

Xcode : `11.5`

Webkit source code obtained from git:

`git clone git://git.webkit.org/WebKit.git webkit`

next build:

```
./Tools/Scripts/set-webkit-configuration --asan
./Tools/Scripts/build-webkit
```

I got info at the end that build succeeded :

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED ** [2.393 sec]


====================================================================
 WebKit is now built (1h:03m:30s). 
 To run Safari with this newly-built code, use the
 "Tools/Scripts/run-safari" script.
====================================================================
```

Trying to run below script I endup with an error:

```
MagicTerminal:webkit joe$ ./Tools/Scripts/run-safari
Starting SafariForWebKitDevelopment with DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH set to point to built WebKit in /Users/joe/projects/webkit/WebKitBuild/Release.
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN3WTF19initializeThreadingEv
  Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari
  Expected in: /Users/joe/projects/webkit/WebKitBuild/Release/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
 in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari
```

Any idea how to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

For now, just revert commits behind this one : https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/263635/webkit